# How fold two arrays by concating and uniquing them but mostly keep positions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to fold two arrays together and retain their positions

```
expect(fold([1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 4])).to.eql([1, 2, 3, 4])
expect(fold([5, 1, 17, 9, 3], [1, 17, 2, 9])).to.eql([5, 1, 17, 2, 9, 3])
```

My ultimate goal is to have this

```
expect(diff([a, b, d, e], [b, c, d])).to.eql({
  foldedList: [a, b, c, d],
  added: [c], // elements that where in 2nd but not in 1st array
  removed: [e]  // elements that where in 1st but not in 2nd array
})
```

For the `added`and `removed` stuff there are solutions, but I found nothing for the folding of the arrays.

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/combining-js-arrays

Comment: thats not what I was looking for. Simply concatenating does not cut it. Elements have to be merged into each another

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your first goal

```
function fold(_a, _b){
  var result = [];
  for(var ind = 0, ln = Math.max(_a.length, _b.length); ind < ln; ind++){
    if (_a[ind] && result.indexOf(_a[ind]) === -1) result.push(_a[ind]);
    if (_b[ind] && result.indexOf(_b[ind]) === -1) result.push(_b[ind]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: nice, but fails in this case: `expect(fold([5, 1, 9, 3], [9, 2, 17, 3], lth)).to.eql([5, 1, 9, 2, 17, 3])`

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly complicated solution

```
function fold(arr1, arr2, sort) {
  function byOrigPositions(a, b) {
    var indexA1 = arr1.indexOf(a)
    var indexA2 = arr2.indexOf(a)
    var indexB1 = arr1.indexOf(b)
    var indexB2 = arr2.indexOf(b)
    if (indexA1 >= 0 && indexB1 >=0) {
      return indexA1 - indexB1
    }
    if (indexA2 >= 0 && indexB2 >=0) {
      return indexA2 - indexB2
    }
    if (sort) {
      return sort(a, b)
    }
    return 0
  }

  return arr2.reduce(function(res, el) {
    if (res.indexOf(el) < 0) {
      res.push(el)
    }
    return res;
  }, [].concat(arr1)).sort(byOrigPositions)
}
```

It sorts after concat and uses the positions in the original arrays as sort function. As a bonus you can give a sort function as third parameter if the positions can't be figured out that way.

Answer (score 0):

I found an rather ugly answer but it works better than my previous one:

```
function fold(arr1, arr2) {
  var res = [];
  var currIndex = 0
  var otherIndex = 0
  var curr = arr1
  var other = arr2
  var i = 0;
  function switchVal() {
    var tmpIndex = otherIndex
    var tmp = other
    otherIndex = currIndex
    other = curr
    curr = tmp
    currIndex = tmpIndex
  }
  do {
    var indexInOther = other.indexOf(curr[currIndex], otherIndex)
    if (indexInOther >= 0) {
      var prevItems = other.slice(otherIndex, indexInOther + 1)
      res = res.concat(prevItems)
      otherIndex = indexInOther + 1
      currIndex++
      switchVal()
    } else if (currIndex < curr.length) {
      res.push(curr[currIndex])
      currIndex++
    } else {
      switchVal()
    }
  } while(currIndex < curr.length || otherIndex < other.length)
  return res
}
```

It switches between the two arrays and tries to find the current element in the other array. If it founds it, it switches references to both arrays and does the same thing the other way around.